# SSH2 PHP compress directory EOF error

Tags: php, gzip, shell-exec

I have a script that does a backup using php and the ssh2 library. 
The script connects to a remote machine using ssh2 and performs the backup tasks. 
I would like to compress the backup directory in order to minimise the downloading time.

I managed to do it but when I open my compressed file in my local machine it says : 'unexpected end of file' :(

I work on Ubuntu 11.10. and php5. My remote machine runs Centos.

To compress the file I am using tar to archive my backup directory followed by gzip, so I end with a myarchiveddir.tar.gz

Code looks as follows:
        ....

```
    $execO = ssh2_exec($conn,"cd /tmp/;tar -cf {$newFile}.tar myRemoteFolder");
    $execO = ssh2_exec($conn,"cd /tmp/;gzip {$newFile}.tar");
    $output = fclose($execO);
```

I have been trying and researching for a solution but I always seem to end in the same point. Could anyone throw a bit of light to this problem. I am new to ssh2 library so I am a bit green in this field. Im sure it cannot be that complicated tho, it must be something I am missing.

Many Thanks in advance.
Manuel

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't `myRemoteFolder` need a trailing slash `/`?

Comment: Hi Adam, I have checked that out, and tar does archive the folder accordingly. So no problem with trailing slash. I have also noticed that I am able to open the tar.gz file generated in the remote machine but not in my local machine. Now!, I have gzip 1.3.12 in my local machine and 1.3.5 in my remote ????

Comment: It seems to me that there is some problem when I am downloading the tar.gz file. Maybe with the ssh2 session

Comment: Are you using `stream_set_blocking`?

Comment: No, I dont use stream_set_blocking... This is interesting.... I just checked this function in php.net and there is a comment regarding something very similar to what is happening here:

Right at the bottom of the page (http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-blocking.php)

"Warning: if you write too much data to a stream in non-blocking mode and fill the buffer, the excess will be silently discarded. Observed in PHP 4.4.0 under linux."